# Terminology for set-valued functions that are "included" in another function

Tags: graph-theory, notation, terminology, multivalued-functions, set-valued-analysis

I was wondering, if you have $f:A \rightarrow B$ a mapping onto sets, is there appropriate terminology for when, for a subset $C \subseteq A$, you have $g:C \rightarrow D$ that verifies $\forall e \in C$, $g(e) \subseteq f(e)$. If so, is there a proper notation for this?

Comment: $f_{|X}(x)$ is defined iff $x\in X$, and is then *equal* to $f(x)$, so your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed, the notation is confusing, the question is to know whether there is a similar term and notation for when say $g$ is restricted to $X$ w.r.t. $f$ and $g(x) \subseteq f(x)$ wherever $g$ is defined. Is that clearer? I'll edit if so.

Comment: No it is not clearer. What do you mean by "$g$
 is restricted to $X$
 w.r.t. $f$", if it is not $g=f_{|X}$?

Comment: I'll write the definition I have in mind then. Let $f$ be a mapping of $A$ in $B$ a collection of sets. $g$ is defined on $C \subseteq A$ and $\forall e \in C$ we have $g(e) \subseteq f(e)$. This seems close enough to the definition of a restriction for me to think that there might be a term for that, that I don't know.

Comment: So, you are mixing the usual notion of restriction ($h=f_{|X}$) with a new notion for which you want a term and notation ($\forall e\in C,\;g(e)\subseteq h(e)$). Maybe the question would be clearer if you do not mention at all the first notion, and focus on the second one.

Comment: Or maybe just $\mathcal G(g)\subseteq\mathcal G(f)$, if $\mathcal G(f)$ denotes the graph of the binary relation associated to $f:X\to\mathcal P(Y)$: $$\mathcal G(f):=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid y\in f(x)\}$$ and similarly for $g$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: @AnneBauval My question stemmed from a problem on subgraphs of graphs with set-valued labelling functions. So yes this is exactly what I am describing. At this point I dont think that  it has a specific name (which is not a problem, it's not very much used) but I'll let the question open in case someone knows (or has a suggestion)